# How to edit webform's email field default error message?

Tags: 7, webforms

How to edit  webform,s email  field  default error message ?
My case is:
I have to place error message just below the email field for this purpose i have used inline error message module and client side validation ,these modules worked well for me .

But the problem is that  webforms default error message of email field  commimg below the email text (say: your email address is not valide) but i dont want this default error message .suppose i want to print error message (say: you must provide a valid email address) for this i have created a custom validation function but after creating custom validation fuction my error message showing above the text box not below the textbox only default error message showing below the email field by using inline error message module that is not my requirement.

If i change the default error message(say: your email address is not valid) to  (say: you must provide a valid email address) i can acheive the desired task

But how to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

[String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module may be an alternative.

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

Answer (score 0):

[Webform Required message](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_required_message) This module will provide you with an interface so you can custom error messages for required fields.